# Node.js including local javascript file located on web server

Tags: javascript, web-applications, node.js, include

I have a Node.js server at

`var/server/server.js`

And a client at

`var/www/client.js`

Is it possible to include the client.js from within the server somehow, using the file system address so that I can use common functions of the client.js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `var client = require('../www/client.js)` ?

Comment: should that be require(), not include()?

Comment: The methods in the js file aren't attached to any objects.  So when I call client.aMethod() it cannot find the method because it's not inside a object I think?  Anyone got any ideas on how to call these static methods?

Comment: @moz, you could add some conditional exports - e.g:  if (module){ module.exports.func1 = func1; module.exports.func2 = func2;}  then you can say:  client.func1();   since module wouldn't be defined when executed in the client, shouldn't cause any problems.

Answer (score -1):

you can include any js on the internet. so you shell be able to get yours as well...
just add this on your client html site:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="http://yourserver/server.js"></script> 
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="client.js"></script>
```

Comment: the server script is hidden from the client, I should have made that more obvious maybe

Comment: _nodejs_ runs on servers and doesn't necessarily include html stuff.